# pad varchar numbers with 0s in db2

Tags: db2, padding

Is there a way to pad 0s before numbers stored as VARCHAR in DB2?

Like this:

```
some_column     result
-----------     ------
12          ==>  00012
123         ==>  00123
6454        ==>  06454
```

Answer (score 27):

If the function [LPAD](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db29.doc.sqlref/db2z_bif_lpad.htm) is available:

```
SELECT LPAD(some_column, 5, '0')
FROM table
```

Otherwise you can use a combination of [RIGHT](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db29.doc.sqlref/db2z_bif_right.htm) and [REPEAT](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db29.doc.sqlref/db2z_bif_repeat.htm):

```
SELECT RIGHT(REPEAT('0', 5) || some_column, 5)
FROM table

some_column  |  Concatenate five '0's to some_column  | Return the five rightmost characters
------------------------------------------------------------------------
    12       =>             0000012                   =>   00012
   123       =>            00000123                   =>   00123
  6454       =>           000006454                   =>   06454
```