# DB2 SQL Convert Decimal to Character with Padded Zeros

Tags: sql, db2

How can I convert my `DECIMAL(11)` field from `12345678` to a character value of `00012345678`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My LeftPad function without LeftPad function

```
 REPEAT('0', 4-length(MY_COLUMN_VALUE))||CHAR(MY_COLUMN_VALUE) as NEW_COLUMN

MY_COLUMN_VALUE NEW_COLUMN
1               0004
23              0023
```

testing ...

```
SELECT '32' MY_VALUE, REPEAT('0', 4-length('23'))||CHAR('23') as LEFTPAB_MY_VALUE FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Answer (score 18):

Only use the  `DIGITS` function, because this verifies the length of the field numeric or decimal, etc and completes with zeros to the left when is necessary.

```
SELECT DIGITS(FIELD) FROM ...
```

The length of the resulting string is always:

- 5 if the argument is a small integer
- 10 if the argument is a large integer
- 19 if the argument is a big integer

Comment: You may use `RIGHT()` around it to gain the desired number of digits.

Answer (score 11):

Based on your comment in @Mr Fuzzy Botton's answer, I'm guessing you're on [`DB2 for i`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp), which does not have the `LPAD` function. You could instead use a combination of the [`REPEAT`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzscarepeat.htm) and [`RIGHT`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzscaright.htm)functions:

```
SELECT RIGHT(REPEAT('0', 11) || LTRIM(CHAR(your_field)), 11)
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 10):

Using http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2.doc.sqlref/castsp.htm for details on CAST
and http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_scalarfunctionsintro.htm for string functions,
I assume this should do the trick -

`SELECT LPAD(  CAST(FIELD AS CHAR(11))  ,11,'0') AS PADDEDFIELD`

Comment: I'm getting LPAD in *LIBL type *N not found.

Comment: Well, I tried, not a db2 user :) .... see here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964244/pad-varchar-numbers-with-0s-in-db2

Comment: LPAD function is available only on the DB2 for `zOS`.

Comment: lpad( cast( F2 as int),5,'0')  this worked for me on iseries

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if you've worked it out, however try this:

```
SELECT LPAD( DIGITS( fieldName ), 11, '0') ) as paddedFieldName FROM yourTable
```

The LPAD is the left padding, but the DIGITS function was the only way I got DB2 to treat the numeric value like a string.

Answer (score 1):

If this is DB2 for i, and myColumn data type is DECIMAL with precision (11) and scale (0), then:

```
SELECT digits( myColumn ) FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

will return:

```
....+....1.
DIGITS     
00001234567
```

Changing the number of leading zeros could be done in many ways. CASTing to a different precision before using DIGITS() is one way.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( 
          CHAR(100000000000+fieldName),
          2,11
       ) as paddedFieldName
FROM yourTable
```

I only wanted to define my field once in the select statement so the above worked for me and is tidy

Answer (score 0):

I just went the other direction: cast(field as int)

Comment: What does that have to do with the question? I don't see any need of CASTing to INT.

Comment: The db2 lpad function appears to be overloaded with integer as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your field x:

```
substr(digits(x), 33 - length(x), length(x) )
```

Answer (score -1):

From Numeric 8,0 (datenumfld=20170101) to `01/01/2017` This works for me:

```
DATE(TO_DATE(CHAR(datenumfld), 'YYYYMMDD')) as YourDate
```

Comment: The question has nothing to do with dates.