# Add leading zeros on an sql insert statement

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a set of fields(all char) I am writing to a table(**new_table**) from another table(**old_table**). There are **four fields** in old_table - **month, day, century, year**(again, in char). I am adding these dates into new_table as one field - **invdat**(char). The client would like to **add leading zeros to the date** because they are not currently stored in **old_table**.

Here is a sample:

```
INSERT INTO new_table 
SELECT month || oedy01 || oecc01 || oeyr01 || as invdat 
FROM old_table
```

So, I would need to add a leading zero to these fields before putting them into the invdat field in the new_table.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: The first question is why are the date parts stored as separate strings rather than one date? The second question is why you want to build a string from it rather than a date? It's much easier to work with dates when using the date datatype of course.

Comment: Anyway, here is how to left-pad zeros to a string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964244/pad-varchar-numbers-with-0s-in-db2

Comment: I'd try for some client education on this one.  Dates are stored in the 'data layer' while they are displayed on the 'presentation layer'.  The data layer and the format that they are held in are of no concern when it comes to display and padding.  Echo of Thorsten, switch to date fields...you are currently setting up a complete mess for your client to deal with at a later time.

Comment: I agree with you completely. I told them it would be easier, but they are as400 programmers and said this is the way they have done it for 20 years and don't currently plan to change. I'm right out of college and have little pull as a junior developer. If I did want to change these four fields to a date format, how would I go about doing that in this new table? Thank you.

Comment: Use the DATE function with an ISO date string 'yyyy-mm-dd': `date(lpad(year, 4, '0') || '-' || lpad(month, 2, '0') || '-' || lpad(day, 2, '0'))`. Or in case the year is stored as 'yy' only: `date(lpad(century - 1, 2, '0') || lpad(year, 2, '0') || '-' || lpad(month, 2, '0') || '-' || lpad(day, 2, '0'))`.

Comment: What values are stored in OECC01? Also, for other fields such as OEYR01, what value is stored for year 2008 for example? I.e., when you say you need leading zeros, does that mean that a 2-digit year is stored as "8b" or "b8"? ("b" is blank.) I've been an "AS/400" developer for more than 20 years, and most of the time has included trying to convince many others to use DATE, TIME and TIMESTAMP data types. It's disturbing when it's not done. The systems often have other troubling elements that are no longer appropriate.

Comment: ...they're nuts.  You should tell them that the date type will take **LESS** space than any character encoding they devise (4 bytes vs the minimum 7 they need here).  Plus preventing all sorts of stupid update and maintenance errors (ask them about leap years).  The only plus side this scheme has is it makes rolling up by month easier (likelier to hit an index)... but starting with year is generally more useful.  A Calendar table would serve them far, far better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many reasons why a system with older software is storing dates as a character string.  Quite likely, it's because the software was written before date data types were easily available in RPG.  A comment above mentions it's been done this way for 20 years.  There is probably a LOT of code around it and changing it to satisfy "newer" conventions is cost prohibitive.  Even though DB2/400 and RPG IV handle dates quite nicely today, who wants to re-code and re-test a big system that's been working just fine for decades when there is other work to be done?  That said, here is a simple way, using AS/400-happy DB2 SQL, to zero-pad your fields into a single date field:

```
INSERT INTO new_table 
SELECT Right('00'||month,2) || Right('00'||oedy01,2) || Right('00'||oecc01,2) || Right('00'||oeyr01,2) as invdat 
FROM old_table
```

I suggest verifying that date format with the AS/400 developers.  Normally, you'll see a date stored that way in ccyymmdd format, but there's no hard and fast rule about that.

Comment: That's what they told me about the dates when I asked them. They said back when they started(early 80's) on the code base they were still programming in RPGIII. But, this solution works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Per typical, the OP did not give their DDL.

FWiW, there can be great advantage in having stored separate components of dates, **if** the majority of query activity depends on those components and they are indexed; though with the additional capability of derived INDEX, the expressions such as YEAR(date_field) or SUBSTR(mmddyyyy_string_field, 5, 4) as the key can ameliorate the issues with run-time derivations against which to perform those selections.  The conversion to the described INVDAT, in the chosen format, is not all that *good* of a choice IMO, even if most of the selections are not against the specific date-components; I comment on that later.

While one might expect the accepted answer should give generally correct results, because of the expectations for the domain of the data being apparent date-values of at least one digit [string or numeric], the results are quite dependent on the data-typing; tellingly, per the "leading zeros … are not currently stored" in the old values, the data type is conspicuously character-string vs numeric, and per "(again, in char)" one might expect CHAR vs VARCHAR.  And as string-data, there is no mention of whether the non-zero-padded\prepended stored values might be left-adjusted or right-adjusted.

That and other\future answers and commentary might not be appropriate for the actual and unknown\**unstated** DDL, and thus those responses should be prefaced by an effective "with this DDL as a *given*"; yet also per typical, responders will rarely offer that clarification :-(

For example, the Left Pad (LPAD) scalar [available since IBM DB2 for i 7.1] that was mentioned in a comment already.  While LPAD is a possibly more conspicuously appropriate scalar request for the intended effect than is the use of the longer-existing and quite capable RIGHT scalar [when combined with a prepending of a string of one or more zeroes, as required for the actual data that was also left **undescribed** in the OP, but assuredly valid only when concatenated to a *stripped* value], the LPAD likely also will fail for the OP, because their original data is likely CHAR [per "(again, in char)"] rather than VARCHAR; i.e. the LPAD fails the *common sense* test, per failing to implement the most likely\rational intentions, and instead operates as nothing more than an effective substring against fixed-length CHAR data, despite a SUBSTR function had already long existed for that effect.

Of course with those same inferences about what the OP has for DDL, even the expression `RIGHT('00' CONCAT char_2_field, 2)` fails to produce desirable results; e.g. with the left-adjusted value `'1 '` in the field, that expression is effectively asking for `RIGHT(CHAR('001 ', 4), 2)` for which the result is `'1 '` rather than the presumed-to-be desired `'01'` and with the right-adjusted value `' 1'` in the field, that expression is effectively asking for `RIGHT(CHAR('00 1', 4), 2)` for which the result is `' 1'` rather than the presumed-to-be desired `'01'`.  I was actually a bit surprised that **that answer** was accepted; i.e. I was shocked that, apparently, the original DDL had the fields declared as VARCHAR and that those values apparently also properly stripped when stored or properly cast as such whence they came.

If those fields were VARCHAR or were acted on by STRIP [or LTRIM or similar] to effect that data-typing of varying string [seemingly optionally with the left-trimmed result according to the implications by the docs for the effect of LPAD, but my experience suggests left-trim or fully stripping is advisable], then the string could be generated as expected, for the expressions offered in both the *answer* and the *comment*.

The DATE scalar noted in the comment could be omitted, and the order of the date-components could be reordered.  But as a string instead of a DATE data-typed result, the string formatted as MMDDYYYY shown in the OP **is not** *well-ordered* [lacks the lexicographical quality] so is useless in sorting and in selectivity for anything other than [not] equal predicates; a string formatted as YYYYMMDD [nearly like what that comment attempts to offer] **is** *well-ordered*, thus well suited for sorting and for relative [rather than only match|non-match] selectivity; not having inherent support for DATE arithmetic and validation is a lesser negative.

Note: the following scripted actions for DDL and populating data assume the "cc" refers to the simple counting-century numeric two-digit values; i.e. such that the "cc" ignores a zero-century so a '19' implies 1900s not 1800s, and such that the "cc" is not an alternative mapping such '00'->'19','01'->'20',etc.

The setup for enabling testing of the given and alternate queries:

```
create table old_table
( month    char(2) not null with default
, oedy01   char(2) not null with default
, oecc01   char(2) not null with default
, oeyr01   char(2) not null with default
)
;
create table new_table
( invdat   char(8) not null with default
)
;
insert into old_table /* mm, dd, cc, yy */ values          
  ( ' 1', ' 1', '19', '40' ),  ( '3 ', '3 ', '19', '40' )  
, ( ' 1', ' 1', '20', ' 0' ),  ( '3 ', '3 ', '20', '0 ' )  
, ( ' 2', ' 2', '20', '  ' ),  ( '4 ', '4 ', '20', '  ' )  
, ( ' 1', ' 1', '20', ' 1' ),  ( '3 ', '3 ', '20', '1 ' )  
, ( ' 1', ' 1', '20', '39' ),  ( '3 ', '3 ', '20', '39' )  
, ( ' 1', ' 1', ' 0', ' 1' ),  ( '3 ', '3 ', '0 ', '1 ' )  
, ( ' 2', ' 2', '  ', ' 1' ),  ( '4 ', '4 ', '  ', '1 ' )  
; -- mm(1,2):right-adj, mm(3,4):left-adj, mm(2,4):blank-elems
  -- 14 rows inserted in OLD_TABLE
```

Now for the querying what was setup above:

```
SELECT Right('00'||month,  2) || Right('00'||oedy01, 2)          
    || Right('00'||oecc01, 2) || Right('00'||oeyr01, 2) as invdat
from old_table
where month not in (2, 4)
; -- report of above query follows; no leading zeroes anywhere:
  INVDAT  
   1 11940
  3 3 1940
   1 120 0
  3 3 200 
   1 120 1
  3 3 201 
   1 12039
  3 3 2039
   1 1 0 1
  3 3 0 1 
-- end of data --
select                                                         
  lpad( month  , 2, '0') concat lpad( oedy01, 2, '0') concat   
  lpad( oecc01 , 2, '0') concat lpad( oeyr01, 2, '0') as invdat
from old_table                                                 
where month not in (2, 4)
; -- report of above query follows; no leading zeroes anywhere:
  INVDAT  
   1 11940
  3 3 1940
   1 120 0
  3 3 200 
   1 120 1
  3 3 201 
   1 12039
  3 3 2039
   1 1 0 1
  3 3 0 1 
-- end of data; a duplicate of the prior query report --
```

So with the given setup, the above queries are not very helpful.  With a minor revision to each query to ensure the CHAR data is first stripped of superfluous blanks, the results are much better:

```
select                    
  lpad( strip(   month ) , 2, '0') concat   
  lpad( strip(   oedy01) , 2, '0') concat   
  lpad( strip(   oecc01) , 2, '0') concat   
  lpad( strip(   oeyr01) , 2, '0') as invdat
from old_table                              
/* where month not in (2, 4) -- this *fixes* blank values too */
; -- report of above query follows; expected leading zeroes appear:
  INVDAT  
  01011940
  03031940
  01012000
  03032000
  02022000
  04042000
  01012001
  03032001
  01012039
  03032039
  01010001
  03030001
  02020001
  04040001
-- end of data --
SELECT                                             
    Right('00' concat strip( month ) , 2) concat   
    Right('00' concat strip( oedy01) , 2) concat   
    Right('00' concat strip( oecc01) , 2) concat   
    Right('00' concat strip( oeyr01) , 2) as invdat
from old_table                                     
/* where month not in (2, 4) -- this *fixes* blank values too */
; -- report of above query matches the prior; not repeated here
```

If the DDL were instead numeric and known to have valid decimal data stored for the values, then the following might be a representative script:

```
drop table  old_table
;
create table old_table                  
( month    dec (2) not null with default
, oedy01   dec (2) not null with default
, oecc01   dec (2) not null with default
, oeyr01   dec (2) not null with default
)                                       
;
insert into old_table /* mm, dd, cc, yy */ values        
  ( ' 1', ' 1', '19', '40' ),  ( '3 ', '3 ', '19', '40' )
, ( ' 1', ' 1', '20', ' 0' ),  ( '3 ', '3 ', '20', '0 ' )
, ( ' 1', ' 1', '20', ' 1' ),  ( '3 ', '3 ', '20', '1 ' )
, ( ' 1', ' 1', '20', '39' ),  ( '3 ', '3 ', '20', '39' )
, ( ' 1', ' 1', ' 0', ' 1' ),  ( '3 ', '3 ', '0 ', '1 ' )
; -- notably, no blank values per inability to cast to decimal
select
   digits(month ) concat digits(oedy01) concat   
   digits(oecc01) concat digits(oeyr01) as invdat
from old_table                                       
; -- report from above query follows; DIGITS casting gives leading zeros:
INVDAT  
01011940
03031940
01012000
03032000
01012001
03032001
01012039
03032039
01010001
03030001
-- end of data --
```

Both of the queries offered [the variants that I included in my above examples; the one with the RIGHT() expression and the one with the LPAD()] from the *answer* and in a *comment*, will give the same report as above.  That is because the result of the implicit cast from CHAR to DECIMAL is a left-adjusted varying character string representation of the numeric value, and thus is implicitly left-trimmed and varying-length so those scalar functions will produce desirable output.

If the above script for use of numeric data-types [instead of the alluded "all char" data-types] is the reason the *answer* selected by the OP as acceptable, then that serves to emphasize how poorly-explained the problem scenario was, and implies how easily that could have been prevented, by having included the DDL; and better, to have additionally included sample data.